# Is there an OSX workaround to configure a "unifying" receiver without Logitech's control center?

Tags: wifi, mouse, keyboard

I have two Logitech wireless devices (keyboard and mouse) that work well on my ppc mac (running OSX 10.4.11). Each has a little USB unifying receiver that came with it, each receiver being paired with the device it came with.
 You're supposed to be able to pair both devices to a single receiver, but Logitech wants you to download the Logitech Control Center in order to do so. I just finished "cleaning house" on my system, removing unwanted and residual third-party stuff, and I'd rather not install some "bloatware" if there's a way I can manually pair both devices to one receiver. Add to that the fact that Logitech no longer offers a version of LLC that runs on 10.4.
I've seen some people mentioning SteerMouse and USB Overdrive, and might check them out, but is there any other option? I don't care about customizing the buttons, just pairing both devices to one receiver.
I hope this isn't considered off-topic. I realize the question centers around Logitech, but I'm hoping there's a way to access configuration setting with OSX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the only "workaround" is to install Logitech Control Center, use it to pair the devices with the receiver, then uninstall the LCC software.
I tried both USB Overdrive and MouseSteer first, but neither seems to include the necessary pairing functionality. I uninstalled each, then found an older version of LCC (version 3.3.0) that was compatible with my operating system and processor, used it, took careful note of what and where it was installing on my system, used the included uninstaller, and voila!
Actually, there was some residual stuff that I dug up and deleted manually. I should mention that the LCC installer had a pretty good and thorough ReadMe that actually listed what files would be installed in what locations. It did omit a couple files that I found with a sudo find, but the whole thing was pretty painless.
And now I have a keyboard I like *and a scroll-wheel on my mouse!* I've been living in the dark ages with the one-button magic mouse for a long time :)

Answer (score 0):

Mac does have the Logitech Unifying Software, which opens up the pairing options; add and remove items from a receiver, as well as update firmware (which seems to be perpetually greyed out no matter what I do on my Mac's and PC's, but that's a problem for another day.)

Version 1.1.301 works with OSX 10.4 - 10.6 and is found [here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/38533/logitech-unifying-software).

Otherwise you can get all versions from the [Logitech Support page](http://support.logitech.com/software/unifying).

Not sure if this existed when the post was made, but as an update to the question, it's now a solution.